# problema con la navegacion en ionic v1

Tags: angularjs, ionic, navigationview, navigation, back-button

estoy realizando una navegacion entre un tab y dos vistas aqui mi configuracion de app.js

```
   .state('tab', {
       url: '/tab',
       abstract: true,
       templateUrl: 'templates/tabs.html',
       cache: 'true'
   })

   .state('tab.domiciliarios', {
    url: '/domiciliarios',
    views: {
        'tab-domiciliarios': {
            templateUrl: 'templates/domiciliarios.html',
            controller: 'DashCtrl',
            controller: 'ChatsCtrl'
        }
    }
})

.state('tab.perfilDomiciliario', {
    url: '/perfilDomiciliario/:chatId',
    views: {
        'tab-domiciliarios': {
            templateUrl: 'templates/perfilDomiciliario.html',
            controller: 'ChatDetailCtrl'
        }
    }
})

.state('tab.chats', {
        url: '/chats',
        views: {
            'tab-chats': {
                 templateUrl: 'templates/tab-chats.html',
                controller: 'ChatsCtrl'
            }
        }
    })
.state('tab.chat-detail', {
    url: '/chats/:chatId',
    views: {
        'tab-chats': {
             templateUrl: 'templates/chat-detail.html',
            controller: 'ChatDetailCtrl'
         }
     }
 });
```

desde los tabs los llamo de esta forma

```
href="#/tab/perfilDomiciliario/{{chat.id}}"
href="#/tab/chats/{{chat.id}}"
```

al inicio funciona bien despues de navegar entre las vistas recurrentemente me deja de mostrar el botón de retroceso[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, proba <a ui-sref="tab.chat-detail({ chatId: chat.id })"> y fijate si se resuelve mejor que con el link directo

Comment: sigue la falla, tengo las vistas en cache="true" @GerardoRosciano

Comment: cual es el codigo del back button?

Comment: yo uso el recomendado por ionic                                                      
 <ion-nav-bar>
  <ion-nav-back-button>
  </ion-nav-back-button>
</ion-nav-bar> en el index y en la vista solo inicio con <ion-view> @GerardoRosciano

Comment: Parece ser un problema común, en mi caso lo solucioné con ui-sref en todos lados. prueba esto en el controller donde desaparece: $ionicNavBarDelegate.showBackButton(true). Espero funcione, saludos!

Comment: y las cache-view de las vistas como las coloco true o false? @GerardoRosciano

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59651/discussion-between-frd-and-gerardo-rosciano).